# Convert JSONArray to String Array with custom format

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I want to ask a question about converting a jsonArray to a StringArray on android. Here is my code to get jsonArray

```
0:{Value: "0", Display: "w"}
1:{Value: "22", Display: "1w"}
2:{Value: "30", Display: "w2"}
3:{Value: "45", Display: "w3"}
```

i want convert this format

```
{"0":"w","22":"w2","30":"w2","45":"w3"}
```

this my code

```
 cols = [
        {
            Id: 'combo',
            Values: [
                        { "Value": "0", "Display": "w" },
                        { "Value": "22","Display": "1w" },
                        { "Value": "30",  "Display": "w2" },
                        { "Value": "45", "Display": "w3" }
                  ],
        },
]
 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(cols.Values).replace("]", "").replace("[", "").replace("},{", "");
```

this result

```
"{"Value":"0","Display":"w""Value":"22","Display":"1w"},
                                                 {"Value":"30","Display":"w2""Value":"45","Display":"w3"}"
```

Comment: sice you hardcode your input then why not make it initally in the way you want finally. Why extra code? Hard-code the desired format itself.

Comment: Is `{"0":"w","22":"w2","30":"w2","45":"w3"}` your desired output? That's not a string array, it's an object. (Or it's an object encoded as a JSON string - can't tell without more context.) Also, what if the input array has more than one item with the same `"Value"`? You might do better retagging the question as "JavaScript" rather than "jQuery".

Comment: this output is format jqgrid combo ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your input and create your desired output like below:-

```js
cols = [
        {
            Id: 'combo',
            Values: [
                        { "Value": "0", "Display": "w" },
                        { "Value": "22","Display": "1w" },
                        { "Value": "30","Display": "w2" },
                        { "Value": "45","Display": "w3" }
                  ],
        },
];// this input is coming form somwhere

obj = {};

$.each(cols[0].Values,function(key,value){
   obj[value.Value] = value.Display;
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

***Note:-***  *"jQuery library is must to add"* for the above code.

***Or you could*** just use the standard `.forEach()` function instead of `$.each()`, and then this code wouldn't need jQuery.

***Example with `.forEach()`:-***

```js
cols = [
        {
            Id: 'combo',
            Values: [
                        { "Value": "0", "Display": "w" },
                        { "Value": "22","Display": "1w" },
                        { "Value": "30","Display": "w2" },
                        { "Value": "45","Display": "w3" }
                  ],
        },
];// this input is coming form somwhere

obj = {};


cols[0].Values.forEach(function(value) {
  obj[value.Value] = value.Display;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: *"jQuery library is must to add"* - Or you could just use the standard array `.forEach()` method instead of `$.each()`, and then this code wouldn't need jQuery.

Comment: @nnnnnn  yes nice pointer. Added in my note section.Thanks for this